# How do I output HTML (created by PHP) with hook_block_view?

Tags: drupal

I want to output something like the following from a hook_block_view function, for a Drupal 7 module that I am creating:

```
$block['subject'] = NULL;
$block['content'] = array(
  'list' => array(
    '#theme' => 'item_list',
    '#type' => 'ol',
    '#items' => $topics
   )
 );
```

...but I don't want to just output a simple ordered list like:

```
<ol>
  <li>Topic 1</li>
  <li>Topic 2</li>
</ol>
```

...I want the list to have some more HTML markup above and below it, and I want this HTML markup to be generated by some PHP.

How do I acheive this in the hook_block_view function?

Comment: `#prefix` and `#suffix` would be an option, or possibly `#theme_wrappers`

Comment: Thanks. The prefix/suffix approach goes some way to solving the problem ...and the theme wrapper approach too (I used this article http://www.disobey.com/node/1893) ...but both methods seem to support the addition of wrapping content in HTML only, not PHP generated HTML. It's probably time I bought a book.

Comment: [Pro Drupal Development](http://www.drupalbook.com/) is awesome

Comment: On a different topic, have you ever tried to implement jQuery UI autocomplete - to kick in when you type something in the search form of a D7 site?

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply put the html string data in $block['content']

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom theme and pass it your $topic variable as params:

```
$block['content'] = theme('my_custom_theme', $topic);
```